# Mixture Proposal Distributions

Tags: markov-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, metropolis-hastings

I have a target distribution $\mu$ which I would like to investigate using, for instance Metropolis-Hastings-Green (MHG).  So, given a Gaussian prior, $\pi$, and a likelihood $L$ such that $\mu(dx) \propto L(x) \pi(dx)$, I can proceed with the standard MHG with random walk proposals from the prior.  But in the problems I'm interested in, I know I have multimodality in $\mu$, so I would like to use a multimodal proposal distribution, such as a mixture of two Gaussians, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.  Assuming I have likelihoods for each of these, $L_1$ and $L_2$, and I have chosen mixture weights, $w_1 + w_2 =1$, I can certainly sample from $w_1 \pi_1 + w_2\pi_2$.  My question is that now I want to run MHG on top of this, and it's unclear to me how to set up the Metropolis ratio for accepting/rejecting the proposal.  I've looked a bit in the literature, but haven't seen anything.

Comment: I don't understand the setting - there may be some notational confusion. In what sense do the components of the _proposal_ have "likelihoods"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Ok, this is admittedly a bit mangled.  I have a target measure and I can express it with respect to two different priors, $\pi_j$, which are easy to sample from.  The problem I really have in mind is that $\mu \propto e^{-V(x)}$ where $V$ is a double well, and each of the $\pi_j$'s models one of the basins.  I'm thinking that the mixture of the two priors should better model the target measure $\mu$, and I would like to formulate a sampling strategy using this mixture.

Comment: Do you know $V(x)$ (Nonrandom? Can be evaluated at least pointwise?)? I suspect you are using the word prior in a nonstandard manner - if the target distribution arises from something else than a Bayesian model, I don't think there should be a "prior" or a "likelihood" involved at all. I also don't see why the mixture representation would complicate setting up the acceptance ratio (at least if $x$ lives in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ with fixed $n$)? Explicitly writing the $V(x)$, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ for the particular case might help to clarify the question.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, $V(x) = .25 (x^2-1)^2$, and $\mu\propto \exp(-V(x)dx$.  $\pi_j(dx) \propto\exp(-(x-j)^2/2)dx$, with $j=\pm 1$.  Focusing on one of the $\pi_j$, I could write down a change of measure between $\mu$ and $\pi_j$, use $\pi_j$ for a proposal and then accept/reject in the usual way.  Since it's multimodal, it would be nice to have a mechanism for exploring both modes, which I figured I could somehow do with a mixture.  Except I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: What is $\pi_j$? Is your intended proposal $w_1\pi_1 +  w_2\pi_2$, independent of the current state? And there are no other "components" in the setting? I don't understand what the likelihoods $L_1$ and $L_2$ mentioned in the question are. Also, if I understand the question correctly, I don't see any complications arising from the mixture - just plug in the densities?

Comment: The $\pi_j$ are the Gaussians, $N(j,1)$, with $j=\pm 1$.  The likelihoods are then proportional to $d\mu/d\pi_j(x)$, i.e., $\exp((x-j)^2/2 - .25(x^2-1)^2)$.  As a model problem, correct, that's all I'm thinking about.  The problem is that in the Metropolis step, to preserve reversibility, I'm confused how to handle the mixture distribution.

Comment: But I don't see why there are likelihoods and priors involved if your target is not a Bayesian posterior. Let alone why there are two "likelihoods".  Are you somehow using "prior" to mean "proposal" and "likelihood" to mean "target / proposal"?. Also, why does the mixture proposal change anything - the acceptance ratio is computed just like with any other proposal - just use the density of the mixture (but this leads me to suspect I don't understand the question and you are trying to do something more complicated)

Comment: I mean, as far as I understand the setting, your target has density $f(x) \propto \exp(-V(x))$ and your proposal (if it's meant to be independent of current state) has density $g(x_{new} \mid x_{old}) = w_1\,g_1(x_{new}) + w_2\,g_2(x_{new})$. These densities are all with respect to the same dominating measure (Lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}$ in this example)? The  acceptance probability would then be simply $\min(1,~\frac{\exp(-V(x_{new})}{\exp(-V(x_{old})}\,\frac{w_1\,g_1(x_{old})+w_2\,g_2(x_{old})}{w_1\,g_1(x_{new})+w_2\,g_2(x_{new})})$.